# Repairing small damage to outside corners. Plaster walls.

Tags: repair, lath-and-plaster

I'm thinking of using bondo. Is there a less-complex way to do it. I'm concerned that regular plaster material will fall off.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Use plaster, 2-part body filler will be just as likely to fall off upon impact and is more difficult to use (IMO).

Rough up the areas around the repair to improve adhesion. Moisten the existing damaged area before carefully applying plaster repair. Mix it to a firm putty consistency then use a moistened wide putty knife to "feather" the plaster back onto the adjacent wall areas. Sand smooth.

You might consider using a corner protector for areas subject to frequent bumps, they come in all colors and sizes including clear:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Good after-construction solutions.

Answer (score 1):

The pro solution involves a metal corner reinforcement, which the plaster is brought flush with before painting. That harder surface is less likely to suffer damage from impact, and can usually just be spot-painted rather than needing to be repaired. But I'm not sure there's a good way to retrofit that.